# Remove duplicate entries in a Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to remove duplicate entries from a text file, e.g:

```
kavitha= Tue Feb    20 14:00 19 IST 2012  (duplicate entry) 
sree=Tue Jan  20 14:05 19 IST 2012  
divya = Tue Jan  20 14:20 19 IST 2012  
anusha=Tue Jan 20 14:45 19 IST 2012 
kavitha= Tue Feb    20 14:00 19 IST 2012 (duplicate entry)
```

Is there any possible way to remove the duplicate entries using a Bash script?

**Desired output**

```
kavitha= Tue Feb    20 14:00 19 IST 2012 
sree=Tue Jan  20 14:05 19 IST 2012  
divya = Tue Jan  20 14:20 19 IST 2012  
anusha=Tue Jan 20 14:45 19 IST 2012
```

Comment: Ironic that this question itself is a duplicate...

Answer (score 492, accepted):

You can `sort` then `uniq`:

```
$ sort -u input.txt
```

Or use `awk`:

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++' input.txt
```

Comment: Testing with an 18,500 line text file: `sort ...` takes about 0.57s whereas `awk ...` takes about 0.08s because `awk ...` just removes duplicates without sorting.

Comment: @Hugo I can second that. Testing against 2,626,198 lines `awk` beats `sort`. Results show `awk` taking 5.675s and `sort` taking 5.675s. Interestingly enough the same record set took 15.1 seconds to perform a MySQL DISTINCT query on.

Comment: @TeganSnyder You wrote the both commands took exactly same time to execute. Didn't `awk` take less time?

Comment: @jarno - my apologizes that was copy paste error on my part. I would need to recreate the test to see how much faster `awk` was, but it was negligible.

Comment: @Hugo is there an elegant way to make this work with case insensitive? or is it better to just convert the entire doc to lowercase, then run this?

Comment: @Onichan Try something like this: `echo -e "c\nb\nB\na" | LC_COLLATE=C -u input.txt` http://superuser.com/q/178171/83235

Comment: tested with 24 million rows, awk did not come to a result within 20 minutes. sort + uniq did the job in some secs.

Comment: I downvoted this because, although poster is happy, folks could be confused by an answer that does not yield the desired output, as it sorts the input

Comment: tried it like this: for i in $(ls .*ini); do awk '!a[$0]++' $i; done and it erased some files entirely

Comment: @bhelm Re: "24 million rows": any ideas _why_ awk did not come to a result within 20 minutes?

Answer (score 21):

It deletes duplicate, consecutive lines from a file (emulates "uniq").
First line in a set of duplicate lines is kept, rest are deleted.

```
sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

Comment: worked for me, One more addition for other use, If you want to change the file itself here is the command `sed -i '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' <FileName>`

Comment: This is awesome !!

Comment: what is `$!N; `?

Answer (score 13):

Perl one-liner similar to @kev's awk solution:

```
perl -ne 'print if ! $a{$_}++' input
```

This variation removes trailing whitespace before comparing:

```
perl -lne 's/\s*$//; print if ! $a{$_}++' input
```

This variation edits the file in-place:

```
perl -i -ne 'print if ! $a{$_}++' input
```

This variation edits the file in-place, and makes a backup `input.bak`

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if ! $a{$_}++' input
```

Comment: I like the Perl solution because it allows me to add extra conditions, e.g. only enforce uniqueness on lines matching a certain pattern.

Comment: Is `perl -i -ne 'print if ! $a{$_}++' input` faster (in genereal) than `gawk -i inplace '!a[$0]++' input`?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cat -n file.txt |
sort -u -k2,7 |
sort -n |
sed 's/.*\t/    /;s/\([0-9]\{4\}\).*/\1/'
```

or this:

```
 awk '{line=substr($0,1,match($0,/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)+3);sub(/^/,"    ",line);if(!dup[line]++)print line}' file.txt
```