# Use awk or sed to eliminate repeat entries in text file

Tags: linux, bash, text, awk, sed

I have a text file like this...

```
apples
berries
berries
cherries
```

and I want it to look like this...

```
apples
berries
cherries
```

That's it. I just want to eliminate doubled entries. I would prefer for this to be an awk or sed "one-liner" but if there's some other common bash tool that I have overlooked that would be fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate entries using a Bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377040/remove-duplicate-entries-using-a-bash-script)

Comment: Is the input sorted? Are the duplicates always adjacent?

Comment: I am piping output from /usr/share/dict/words so it is always in alphabetical order and the duplicates are always adjacent. But if I start using a different dictionary in the future they might not be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sort -u file
```

if in case you are not worried about the order of the output.

Remove duplicates by retaining the order:

```
awk '!a[$1]++' file
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a special command for this task, called `uniq`:

```
$ uniq file
apples
berries
cherries
```

This requires that common lines are adjacent, not adjacent equal lines are not removed.