# Delete repeated text between delimeters

Tags: bash, duplicates

I have a data file for [fortune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)) that contains many repeated fortunes. I would like to remove them.

Fortunes are delineated by `%`'s, so a sample fortune file may look like this:

```
%
This is sample fortune 1
%
This is 
sample fortune 2
%
This fortune 
is repeated
%
This is sample fortune 3
%
This fortune 
is repeated
%
This fortune
is unique
%
```

As you can see, fortunes can span across multiple lines, rendering the [solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377040/remove-duplicate-entries-using-a-bash-script) useless.

What can I do to find and remove the repeated fortunes? I thought about just finding a way to make `awk` ignore lines beginning with `%`, but some fortunes share identical lines but are not the same overall (such as the last two in my example), so that is not enough.

I've been trying to solve this with `awk` so far, but any tool is fine.

Comment: see also answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744733/fortune-with-m-exclude-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a job for `awk`:

```
awk 'seen[$0]{next}{seen[$0]=1}1' RS='%' ORS='%' fortune
```

`RS='%'` means we are using `%` as the record separator.

`seen[$0]` checks if we already have seen this value. `$0` is the whole record, the fortune's text, as string. If we've seen the value we are moving to the next record and don't print anything.

`{seen[$0]=1}` adds the record to the lookup table. `1` prints the current record since it is always true. Note that this code gets only executed when we've not seen the record before, because of the `next` statement before.

`ORS='%'` set's the output record separator to `%`.

Comment: I was not aware of the `RS` and `ORS` variables. That was key thing I was missing.

Comment: Indeed, they are very powerful! I suggest to always think about *records* instead of *lines*

Answer (score 4):

Awk can handle it.  Set the record separator to `"%\n"` and then print unique entries:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="%\n"} { if (! ($0 in fortunes)) { fortunes[$0]++; print $0 "%"} }' data
%
This is sample fortune 1
%
This is 
sample fortune 2
%
This fortune 
is repeated
%
This is sample fortune 3
%
This fortune
is unique
%
$
```