# Fortune with -m exclude string

Tags: regex, bash, scripting, escaping

I'm try to use fortune-mod version 9708 on CentOS 7 to only show oneliners. So I need to prevent fortunes that show the author on a second line.
So this fortune is one I don't want to see:

```
> fortune -s -n 65
Whip me.  Beat me.  Make me maintain AIX.
        -- Stephan Zielinski
```

As a test I tried with 'Evil'. This is the result of all fortunes that contain Evil:

```
> fortune -s -n 65 -m Evil
(bofh-excuses)
%
Evil dogs hypnotized the night shift
%
(paradoxum)
%
  Evil isn't all bad.
%
```

So how can I get a fortune that does not contain 'Evil'.
I tried:

```
> fortune -s -n 65 -m ((?!Evil).)*
> fortune -s -n 65 -m ((?\!Evil).)*
> fortune -s -n 65 -m "((?!Evil).)*"
> fortune -s -n 65 -m '((?!Evil).)*'
```

And many more combinations. Using a ! breaks the command. Escaping it does not seem to work. Any tips how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to quote your patterns, or your patterns are interpreted by bash rather than passed as a command line argument. Also, I'm not sure pcre is understood (most likely not).

Comment: Als tried with quotes (edited question)

Comment: Ah ok, and there is absolutely no method to exclude a string without pcre?

Comment: If we're talking about BRE/ERE here, then there's no negative lookahead/lookbehind. Can't you write a function wrapper that use a `while` loop to get an adage without `Evil` (or any pattern, for that matter), though?

Comment: Well if there is no other way, I guess I can. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Just loop until you've found a one line fortune:

```
while fortune -sn80 |awk 'END { if (NR == 1) { print; exit 1 } }'; do true; done
```

The `while` loop will keep going until `awk` exits with a nonzero value, which only happens when we've found our one-liner.  The `awk` code reads the whole fortune and then, at the end, checks to see if the number of records (`NR`, the line count) is one.  If so, print the last (the only) line and exit the `while` loop.

I assume you had used `-n 65` as an effort to limit the size, so I expanded it to 80.  Obviously, you can remove it, return it to 65, or change it to another value as you see fit.

---

Here's a variant that accepts one-line quotes (with a second line of attribution) and prints on one line:

```
while fortune -sn80 |awk '
  NR == 1 { L = $0 }
  NR == 2 && $1 == "--" { NR--; $1 = " --"; $0 = L $0 }
  END { if (NR == 1) { print; exit 1 } }
'; do true; done
```

This adds two conditionals.  First, we track the content of line 1.  Second, if line two has `--` as its first whitespace-delimited content, decrement the line count and replace the leading whitespace with a single space (altering `$1` causes `$0` to be respaced), and prepend the previous line so the final clause only sees one line.

So e.g. this quote:

```
Don't Worry, Be Happy.
                -- Meher Baba
```

is now accepted after becoming:

```
Don't Worry, Be Happy. -- Meher Baba
```

---

To exclude `Evil` (a noble pursuit ):

```
while fortune -sn80 |awk '
  END { if (NR == 1 && !index($0, "Evil")) { print; exit 1 } }
'; do true; done
```

All I did was say there is no index for "Evil" in the final condition. You could use an extended regex instead with `(NR == 1 && ! /Evil/)` although note that `awk` regexes do not allow numeric quantifiers (so `/a+/` is fine but `/a{1,}/` and `/a{1,9}/` won't work). If you want case-insensitive, you have to do `tolower($0) !~ /evil/`.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. Might take some time. My goal is to integrate this in my MotD generator: https://outsideit.net/generate-motd

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on the idea of running `fortune` until it produces a single line of output:

```
while fortune=$(fortune -sn80) ; [[ $fortune == *$'\n'* ]] ; do : ; done
```

It loops until the output does not contain an internal newline character.  Then the single-line output is in the `fortune` variable.