# How to get unique values (lines) in a txt file that have duplicated lines using unix?

Tags: linux, duplicates, unique

I have a txt file with different lines:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
ababab
ababab
ababab
ababab
```

And I want to remove duplicates **but**get the first value:
**expected**

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
ababab
```

I've tried `sort file | uniq -u` but the expected result did not include the sole coincidence for the row `ababab`

Any help?

Comment: solved, I've just use `sort file | uniq` and it works!

Comment: Just omit the `-u` and you'll get what you want. And its `uniq`, not `unique` :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete duplicate lines in a file in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1444406/608639), [Remove duplicate entries using a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9377040/608639), [How to remove duplicate files using bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192701/56041), [How to remove duplicated files in a directory?](https://superuser.com/q/386199/173513), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just uniq

```
$ cat file
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
ababab
ababab
ababab
ababab

$ cat file | uniq
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
ababab

$ sort file | uniq -u
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is:

```
 awk '!a[$0]++' file
```

Note that, using `sort|uniq` may change the order of the lines in the file. The awk line above won't.