# git log exclude renames

Tags: git

I can list commits for a file, even if it has been renamed or moved

```
git log --follow foo.sh
```

However, I would like to "follow" the file, but only list commits where the file was actually changed. Something like

```
git log --follow --exclude-renames foo.sh
```

Comment: I tried to filter it by commit message with `--grep="renamed:" --invert-grep` but for me this did not work. But the oposide direction `--grep="renamed:"` forks and shows only commits containing the "renamed:" test in the message.

But keep in mind that it if only a filtering by message, this can not respect commits with mixed renames and changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
git log --follow --name-status --oneline foo.sh | sed 'h;N;/\nR/d;g'
```

- copy commit line to hold space
- read in second line
- if line starting with `R` is found, delete pattern space and start next cycle, 
  else copy hold space to pattern space

thanks to [`jthill`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731)

Answer (score 2):

just found `--diff-filter` option, which you can exclude renames by

```
--diff-filter=r
```

so,

```
git log --follow --diff-filter=r foo.sh
```

thanks for @Zombo answer about `--name-status` option

Answer (score 1):

A bit like in "[nicely display file rename history in git log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13579446/6309)", you could add `--name-status` in order to:

- not select (`grep -v` renames: status '`Rxxx`', while keeping addition '`A`' or modification '`M`')
- still follow the file through its different name

But that will still involve post-processing the git log command (with grep and/or sed) in order to get the output you want: there is no native '`--exclude-renames`'-like option yet.

Comment: seeing as how the '--exclude-renames' option is exactly two bytes shorter than just supplying the sed to do it, I have a hard time seeing the point of yetanotheroptionname ...  :-)