# Specific git-log output style

Tags: git, logging, formatting, gource

How can I use `git log --pretty=format""` to output a git log in this format

```
timestamp|username|type|file    
1275543595|andrew|A|src/main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Crude, but gets the job done

```sh
git log --name-status --format='%ct|%an' hulu.sh |
  sed 'N;N;s/\n/|/;s///;s/\t/|/'
```

- append 2 lines to pattern space
- replace first newline with `|`
- remove second newline
- replace tab with `|`

```
1363415345|Steven Penny|M|hulu.sh
1363403048|Steven Penny|M|hulu.sh
1363278409|Steven Penny|M|hulu.sh
1363201389|Steven Penny|M|hulu.sh
1363158212|Steven Penny|M|hulu.sh
```

[git log exclude renames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15130597/git-log-exclude-renames)

Comment: Thanks! What's the hulu.sh bit for and it outputs wrong see [here](http://www.github.com/RX14/Modpack_Downloader) for the repo and [here](http://www.rx14.co.uk/log.log) for the log generated

Answer (score 0):

Am i correct in assuming that you are trying to get this format so you can have gource parse it ?

if so, check out : https://github.com/whitewhidow/live-git-for-gource/blob/master/git-live.sh

wich already does this, also, just check the code, so you can figure out how to get the correct format, in case you needed it for something else ..