# Why can I not see changes made to a specific file?

Tags: git, git-log

When I run `git log`, I can see a commit that I created a few days ago, which contains changes to some file (let's call it `x.txt`).

However, when I run `git log -p x.txt`, which should show me the git changes on this file, I can't see the commit in question.

How could this situation be explained?

Comment: Does `git log -- x.txt` include the commit you think it should?

Comment: @VonC No it's not there :(

Comment: What happens if you take the commit SHA-1 that `git log` shows you (call that `XXXXXX`), and do a `git show XXXXXX`? Does it have the change in there? Perhaps the commit you think changed `x.txt` in fact did not change `x.txt`. Perhaps add that to the question, together with what `git diff XXXXXX{,^}` shows.

Comment: I already check it, and when I did git show `XXXXX`, I can see my change on `x.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git log -p`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) uses actually a [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) option (`--patch`)

If `git log -- x.txt` doesn't show at all the expected commit, then it simply means that commit didn't introduced any diff for that file.
A `git diff -- x.txt` for that commit would be empty.

After [extensive discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67457/discussion-between-yarin-gold-and-vonc), this work (which would mean `x.txt` was renamed or moved at some point):

```
git log --follow -M -p -- x.txt
```

---

There is another case where `git log -p -- x.txt` wouldn't include a commit:

That `-p` option will compare a commit with the previous one for a given file, **unless that file was created** (in which case, there is no previous commit for that file)

That means a `git log -p -- x.txt` won't include the first commit, when the file was initially added.
That "diff" would simply be the full content of `x.txt`.

---

In the OP Yarin Gold's case, though:

- `git show <expected_commit_SHA> -- x.txt` returns the expected diff
- [`git show --pretty="format:" --name-only <expected commit>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/6309) does list `x.txt`* (as in /…)
- `git diff <expectedcommit~1> <expectedcommit> -- x.txt` returns (again) the expected change

All that with a git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50) on OS X (10.9.5).

Comment: My change (There is some change on the file) on the file was the second commit (the first one was of course the creation of the file).

Comment: @YarinGold if `git log -- x.txt` doesn't list your second commit, then that second commit didn't introduce any change to `x.txt`. I have rephrased my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: The second commit definitely have some change on the file.

Comment: Maybe some other developer did something that caused it? that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @YarinGold but you said `git log -- x.txt` didn't include that commit? It does mean this commit definitively did *not* introduced any change to `x.txt`, does it not?

Comment: I see your point but it does not the case for me.
I have change on `x.txt` file but it does not show it on `git log -- x.txt`

Comment: @YarinGold does `git show <expected_commit_SHA> -- x.txt` returns any diff?

Comment: @YarinGold and are we talking about the same `x.txt`? (maybe there is a case issue? a `X.txt`?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67457/discussion-between-yarin-gold-and-vonc).

Comment: @YarinGold regarding the rename, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13620202/6309, what a `git log --format='%H%%' --name-only --follow -- x.txt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/%\n\n/ /g'` returns?

Comment: it returns
`d0f768003b9423b42a63426f3d51f3bcd6ec217e%

app/serializers/api/v1/cms/listed_product_serializer.rb
21e85b33c6be5fffa4bf46800b8af1333d7e4876%

app/serializers/api/v1/cms/listed_product_serializer.rb
af8e86070fd9030679781a18ce50a6fe088cc70c%

app/serializers/api/v1/cms/listed_product_serializer.rb`



The `listed_product_serializer.rb` is the `x.txt` in that case.

Comment: @YarinGold strange... not much rename/move there to see. Is that *all* the commits for that file? Would adding `--all` to the `git log` command generates more commits? (or `--all --branches`)

Comment: It's still returns the same results with `--all` or `--all --branches`, it looks like it wasn't renamed, so I still don't understand why `--follow` gives me the missing data.

Comment: @YarinGold indeed... that should be the topic of a separate question (with a link back to this one) in order to focus on that peculiar behavior.