# sed: parse git --line-porcelain output

Tags: git, sed, blame

this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142609/git-discover-which-commits-ever-touched-a-range-of-lines/14300601#14300601), but I think it warrants a separate question.

`git blame --line-porcelain`'s output is something like this

```
27ce485030bf872158ceb011e6bd775d2ead5eeb 9 36 1
author Joao Tavora
author-time 1358179206
committer Joao Tavora
committer-time 1358179206
summary initial commit
boundary
filename test.el
    (defun AB (space task next.task)
242020d0de6363d48d32465299d07239f0a9940f 19 37 1
author Joao Tavora
author-time 1358179709
committer Joao Tavora
committer-time 1358179709
summary reinstate declare
previous 11da1748d905aa9520ee3d6d9ac6a8712db0040f test.el
filename test.el
      (declare (ignore space))
cbfa1ec071dd30a27be82dd041ccc9c384e5ff60 11 38 2
author Joao Tavora
author-time 1358179273
committer Joao Tavora
committer-time 1358179273
summary use thingy
previous 69af7ace6e2b6c006c86e4fd91bf3c15ff8cec07 test.el
filename test.el
      (if (and (some.task.p (task (IP.TASK-thingy task)))
```

How would I use sed (or grep or awk) toparse to filter out just the commit sha
and the comitter-time? In the example above it should yield:

```
27ce485030bf872158ceb011e6bd775d2ead5eeb 1358179206
242020d0de6363d48d32465299d07239f0a9940f 1358179709
cbfa1ec071dd30a27be82dd041ccc9c384e5ff60 1358179273
```

I'd rather not depend on ruby, although a perl one-liner might be OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^[0-9a-f]{40}\b/!d;:a;/\ncommitter-time\b/bb;$!{N;ba};:b;s/\s+.*(\s.*)/\1/' file
```

Comment: whoa nice! I'll accept soon, just wonder if someone can get a generic solution, i.e. one that doesn't break when my code includes something that looks like a commit :-)

Comment: How to change this sed command to concat author-mail instead of commit hash?

Answer (score 0):

This might be completely the wrong thing, but try this:

```
git shortlog --format="%H %ct" -- <filename>
```

You may also want to cut off the first couple of lines with a `tail -n +2` piped after the command.  Granted, this doesn't show line-by-line changes but I'm not sure exactly what pieces you want.

Comment: I really want to parse the output of `--line-porcelain`, this gives something else completely.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that

```
git blame -l -e -t -- file-to-blame | awk '{print $1 " " $3}'
```

almost solves my problem, but does so for authorship time I think. And I would really like to learn to parse `--line-porcelain` output.