# Git command to programatically add a range of lines of a file to the index?

Tags: git

I want a command that would let me do something like:

```
git manual-add some_file.txt 10..20
```

Which would be the equivalent of:

```
git add -p some_file.txt
```

and saying `y` to only the hunk containing lines 10 through 20.

Is there an internal git command that would let me do this?  Is there *any* way it could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `git add -e` command and pass to it as an editor a script (in the example below, it is named `filterpatch`) that will edit the patch up to your requirements (see the "EDITING PATCHES" section in the documentation of [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)):

```
EDITOR="filterpatch 10..20" git add -e some_file.txt
```

For convenience you can add a git alias as follows:

```
git config alias.manual-add '!EDITOR="filterpatch $2" git add -e $1; :'
```

An example of a silly `filterpatch` script that prepends a `foo` prefix to all added lines in the specified range  of the patch:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

sed -i "$1 s/^+\([^+]\)/+foo \1/" "$2"
```

Usage example:

```
git manual-add some_file.txt 13,16
```

So the remaining part is about implementing the `filterpatch` script properly - it must parse the diff and unselect hunks that don't belong to the target range.

Comment: Can you please give me some explanations on how can I configure that *filterpatch* and *bash*

Comment: @Rawand Such an explanation can hardly be given in comment format. Why don't you ask your question as a question?

Answer (score 2):

Add alias to your config:

```
[alias]
        addp = "!sh -c 'git commit -m temp \"$1\" && git log -1 -u -L \"$2\":\"$1\" > ptc.patch && git reset HEAD^ && git apply --cached ptc.patch ' -"
```

Now you could:

```
git addp a.txt 3,4
```

This sequence will:

1. Do a temporary commit with file $1 only.
2. Write patch `ptc.patch` for lines $2 in file $1 using solution from this question - [Git: discover which commits ever touched a range of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142609/git-discover-which-commits-ever-touched-a-range-of-lines).
3. Mixed reset temporary commit.
4. Apply patch to index only, since working directory already contains changes.

Comment: OP did not specify the hunk selection criteria precisely. In my understanding a hunk may be bigger than the stated range of lines (the hunk just needs to fully include those lines). Your solution will generate a partial patch when the specified line range is a subset of the hunk.

Comment: Besides, I think that your `git log` command  misses a `-1` option.

Comment: @Leon, "Your solution will generate a partial patch when the specified line range is a subset of the hunk." - well, this is exactly my understanding, that OP wants to specify range of lines which comprise a hunk precisely.

Comment: OP's explanation through `git add -p` works differently - if the hunk containing lines 10-20 is actually 100 lines long, the entire hunk will be selected.

Comment: Why would he want to specify a range of lines then, if single line number (e.g. 10) yielded exactly same hunk as for (10..20)? Anyway, let's wait for OP reply.

Comment: I want specific lines, yes. in the patch example, youd have to keep splitting or edit if the hunk contained extra lines

Comment: I suggest to replace `git add \"$1\" && git commit -m temp` with `git commit -m temp \"$1\"` so that other possibly staged changes are not included in the throwaway commit.

Comment: @Leon thank you, I haven't really known it is possible to commit a single file in one command. I updated the answer.