# git: blame the previous version of each line changed in a given commit

Tags: git, git-commit, blame

For a given commit, I need to run blame on the previous version of each line changed but said commit.

Having a commit that changes lines 2 and 3 on file a, I want a way to see the output of `git blame commit^` limited to the preamble and the lines 2 and 3.

How can I do that?

### EDIT

Seems like I have to explicitly specify that I'm looking for a way to do the above *programmatically*, and not examining the commit with my own eyes, determining which lines of which files where changed, and then manually run git blame for each single changed file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git blame -- prior commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098256/git-blame-prior-commits)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
git blame <commit>^ -- filename | head -3 | tail -2
```

Comment: This does not actually do what the question asks -- it simply shows the previous commit, regardless of which lines were changed in this one. See some discussion on why this might be difficult here: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-blame-and-finding-previous-version-of-a-line-td2363880.html

Comment: That link is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git log` to trace the evolution of a range of lines.
So if you already know you need to trace lines `2` through `3` on file `a` you can use
`git log -L2,3:a` that's the format `-L:<start>,<end>:<file>`

git log will then only show commits that have touched those lines, and will automatically show you the patch.
You can specify -L as many times as you need.

For more information, see the -L option on [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_options)