# What do "Originally By" and "Copied Or Moved Here By" mean in Git Gui Blame?

Tags: git, git-gui, git-blame

Normally when I hover over lines in Git Gui Blame, it shows a tooltip containing just the commit hash, the author/date, and the comment.

[image]

But I just saw a tooptip that shows 2 commits - titled "Originally by", and then "Copied Or Moved Here By":

[image]

What do those mean, exactly? Does Git Blame somehow detect when lines of code have been moved or copied?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `git blame` has the ability to detect moved or copied lines within a file. This comes from the `-M` option (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame).

The commit sha in the 2nd column is the same as the output from `git blame` with no options. This corresponds to the label "Copied or Moved Here By".

The commit sha in the 1st column is the same as the output from `git blame -M`. This corresponds to the label "Originally By". This commit date will be earlier than (or equal to) "Copied or Moved Here By".

If you look closely when Git Gui Blame window opens, you will see that the commit shas in the 2nd column are displayed first. Then the commit shas in the 1st column are displayed after a delay. This is because it has to run `git blame -M` to look up the "Originally By" commit.