# Trying to extract some information from Git

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

We've recently moved to Git and the developers would like to make away from the inline commenting the company i'm in has always enforced

For example take this function

```
  function myFunc(){

    line1;
    line2;

    // Mr X - 04/04/2017 - Change description 1 -- START
    // Mr Y - 10/10/2017 - Change description 2 -- START
    // Mr Z - 12/10/2017 - Change description 3 -- START
    line3;
    line4;
    // Mr Z - 12/10/2017 - Change description 3 -- END
    // Mr Y - 10/10/2017 - Change description 2 -- END
    // Mr X - 04/04/2017 - Change description 1 -- END

}
```

The argument is that there is no way to demonstrate the same information (the ability to see 3 people having changed line 3/4 at a glance)

Currently "Blame" gets us most the way there on bitbucket, we can see who's changed each line and when, but the diff's are always to a single previous version.

I guess what i'm after is the ability to see a diff from more than just the version before, with clear highlights of who's changed what (or ideally to keep my manager happy identical comments to the example given).

We have licences and are setup on sourcetree / bitbucket if this helps.

Comment: So to clearify the question: You basically want a `git blame` output for a set (where set can also be everything) of commits?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098256/git-blame-prior-commits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git blame -- prior commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098256/git-blame-prior-commits)